# which lightweight SQL Server type could I use on my Dev machine for a C# VS2010 project?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-ce, sql-server-express

Which lightweight SQL Server type could I use on my Dev machine for a C# VS2010 project? (e.g. sql server express, sql server ce, full version etc).

That is, I'm running on a VMWare fusion instance on my MacBook, and just want something to develop against for a C# VS2010 project.  I'm planning on having a simple database (not many tables) but will use Entity Framework.

I haven't used SQL Server before so a quick pointer re what is the best database admin interface/app to use for the version you recommend (e.g. to create database, tables etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably have the least friction/most support with [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/database/) here.  Since you're using Visual Studio, you can do all the table/database creation completely inside VS, no need for another tool.

[There's a walkthrough of creating a database here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233763.aspx), and [a lot more info about Visual Studio's database abilities here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33wwc2yw(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends. For simple work, express is ok. I prefer to still install the dev version for the management tools.

Otherwise just go with the dev version - you have no choice if oyu want more than simple standard SQL on your server anyway. Unless you USE it, sql server is pretty leightweight.

Comment: Are the better tools for things like ease in creating databases, tables, indexes etc?  What's the dev version exactly?

Comment: @Greg - There's an [express version of SQL Server Management Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365247.aspx) that installs with SQL Server Express, it's all included with the install, just make sure it's checked when you install if you want it, otherwise download it from the link in this comment.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server CE (Compact Edition) is the lightest-weight version of SQL Server available.  The database is stored in a single file (.sdf) and the database engine is hosted in-process (e.g. it's not a separate Windows service).  While it supports most standard SQL, there are more advanced features that it does not support, like stored procedures (see more in [this PDF](http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/8/8/e8859616-e95d-41fe-9f81-ff88388d772b/SQLServer%202008CompareComapctExpress.pdf)).  Additionally, there are limitations when using Entity Framework with SQL CE (see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc835494.aspx)).

SQL Express is much more like full SQL Server, but it does require running separate services on your machine, and it does use more resources than SQL CE.  If you plan to transition to using full-on SQL Server at some point, then going with SQL Express is your safest bet.

You can use Visual Studio's built-in [Server Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x603htbk(VS.80).aspx) to administer whatever type of database you have setup, or, alternatively, you can use SQL Server Management Studio (Express), which is more powerful.  I'm not sure if it can be used to administer SQL CE databases.